# Passing data to routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it acceptable to pass object data (some data containing an array not too large) to a dynamic route using state in useLocation? If not, how else can data be passed between routes (data not accessible in a global parent component).

```
// A project component that lists some projects

const Projects = () => {
 const data = {someData}

 return (
  projects ? 
        <section className="grid my-5 grid-cols-1 gap-4 lg:gap-10 lg:grid-cols-2">
            {projects.map((project) => 
                <ProjectCard key={project.index} project={project}/>
            )}
        </section>
  : <h1>Nothing to see here</h1>
 )

// A project card containing some details and a link to open the project in a different route, i want the route to have access to the project data of the project that was clicked
const ProjectCard = ({project}) => {
 return (
  <div>
   <p> Some project details here </p>
   <Link 
      to={`/${project.name}`}
      state={project}
      id={project.index}>
      Open project
   </Link>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: That looks awful. Don't you have `redux` or at least `useContext`?

Comment: Is it acceptable? Sure, it's opinionated, but it'll work. If you haven't any global state, i.e. [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), redux, etc... (*you probably should consider it at this point*) and simply pass ids or references to it then the options are limited: either send it in route state as you have and asked about, or serialize and send in the URL parameterized in the queryString.

Comment: Thanks Fer and Drew, I think it's best to set up global state management at this point. And as you've pointed out use query string. useContext or redux which would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```js
<Link to={`/better_to_have_prefix/${project.name}/${project}/${project.index}`}>
   Open project
</Link>
```

Somewhere in routes

```js
<Route path="/better_to_have_prefix/:paramProjectName/:paramProject/:paramIndex" component={MyProject} />
```

And finally somewhere in component "MyProject"

```js
this.props.match.params.paramProjectName
this.props.match.params.paramProject
this.props.match.params.paramIndex
```

Comment: It seems `project` is an object, not a string, so this solution very well won't work.

Comment: Yes, I see, but if there is a desire ))) and not so many parameters, it can be done in similar way...it looks terrible... it's better to use redux

Comment: From the answers i'm getting a global state management seems like the best way to go. Thanks